# oracle apex interactive grid get status when choose to delete

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

Good Morning!
As in pic I have interactive grid with values and type (Debit or Credit)
and a dynamic action javascript code that calculate sum of both types
the problem is when the user choose to delete a row like the pic , I don't know how to get that status to remove the value of this row from the calculation...
[image]

I have tried to use apex.item("APEX$ROW_STATUS") but it's not giving me any value
anyone can point me to the right direction please....

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the "Interactive Grid cookbook v6" mentioned in [this](https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2019/11/04/apex-ig-cookbook-update-for-19-2/) blog. Page 5 has an example of a page item that is updated on change of an interactive grid. In the implementation you can see how deleted rows are handled:

```
    function update(model) {
        var salKey = model.getFieldKey("SAL"), 
            total = 0;

        console.log(">> starting sum SAL column")
        model.forEach(function(record, index, id) {
            var sal = parseFloat(record[salKey]),  // record[salKey] should be a little faster than using model.getValue in a loop
                meta = model.getRecordMetadata(id);

            if (!isNaN(sal) && !meta.deleted && !meta.agg) {
                total += sal;
            }
        });
        $s("P5_TOTAL", total);
    }
```

The [RecordMetadata](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.2/aexjs/model.html#.RecordMetadata) of a row has a property "deleted" that you can check for the status of a row.